# node mysql data is changed in result

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I made a table with:

```
create table data_ids (id BIGINT(20) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, data_id BIGINT(20) unsigned);
```

I added one row to it and when I

```
SELECT * FROM data_ids;

+----+--------------------+
| id | data_id            |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | 260846479567093761 |
+----+--------------------+
```

As I expect considering that is the info I put in

But when I run

```
pool.query(`SELECT * from data_ids`, function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(rows);
  }
});

[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 1,
    data_id: 260846479567093760 } ]
```

What on earth is going on here?  Why is the data_id changed?

Comment: You realise you have `SELECT * from guild_data` not `data_ids`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[By default `mysql` will automatically cast values to an appropriate JavaScript type](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/blob/a24448026de71769491a8a54cfa1e59bc71fb5ba/Readme.md#type-casting). In the case of numeric types, it will convert to a JavaScript number.

The problem with this is that JavaScript can only accurately represent integers up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991) and your column value exceeds this maximum. You can disable the automatic type casting by setting `typeCast: false` in your connection or query config *or* you can supply your own function that converts values as you see fit.